# How to have different highlight for different errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using [JQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) in an HTML5 project.
I customized the (un)highlight function as:

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    if (element.type === "radio") {
        this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    } else {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-feedback').addClass('has-error has-feedback');
        $(element).closest('.form-group').find('i.glyphicon').remove();
        $(element).closest('.form-group').append('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></i>');
    }
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    if (element.type === "radio") {
        this.findByName(element.name).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    } else {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error has-feedback').addClass('has-success has-feedback');
        $(element).closest('.form-group').find('i.glyphicon').remove();
        $(element).closest('.form-group').append('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i>');
    }
},
errorPlacement: function (error, element) { }
});
```

Now **I need to have a different highlight on the element if the error is "required" or everything else**.

How can I check the element error type?

Comment: Check on this page: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/, maybe you can create your own validation using this informations.

Comment: There is no straightforward way to do what you want with this plugin.